# Retrieving the values of a nested Powershell object via properties in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, powershell, object

C# Newbie here. I am not sure if what I'm going for is even possible.
Basically, I'm trying to read the properties of a system object array **within** a Powershell object in C#.

For simplicity's sake, here is a basic Powershell code that has a similar output:

```
$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value "Yad"
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Title" -Value "C# Noob"
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NotePropety -Name "Machine Services" -Value (Get-Service)

return $object
```

On the C# side of things, I am able to fetch the results by mapping the properties as below:

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();
shell.Commands.AddScript("C:\\Scripts\\Powershell\\TestScript.ps1 -user " + userName);

Collection<PSObject> results = shell.Invoke();

Profile userProfile = new Profile(); //Profile class is declared prior this line


foreach (PSObject psObject in results)
        {
            userProfile.Name = Convert.ToString(psObject.Properties["Name"].Value);
            userProfile.Title= Convert.ToString(psObject.Properties["Title"].Value);
            userProfile.MachineServices= psObject.Properties["Machine Services"].Value;
         }
```

With this, the 'userProfile' object is equivalent to the Powershell output.

Now, the 'MachineServices' property is an object that contains its own set of properties (status, name, and displayname in Powershell). Is it possible to call these properties and retrieve their values?

I tried something similar to below but, of course, I get an error as the Powershell script is completely separate and the properties are unknown to the C# code prior runtime.

```
userProfile.MachineServices.Status
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you investigate `Get-Service` in PowerShell with `.GetType()` you can find out that it returns an `Object` array, where the members are of type `ServiceController`.

I haven't tried it in C# but you should be able to declare `Profile.MachineServices` as `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[]` and then use the assignment

```
userProfile.MachineServices= (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[])(psObject.Properties["Machine Services"].Value);
```

Once C# knows the correct object type, you can access the properties and methods, get IntelliSense and so on.

Comment: thank you Toni. Saw this a little too late and have already packed up for the day. I will try this out first thing tomorrow and let you know how it goes.